# Download products via API in recursion + store it in Postgres -> every recursion consumes more RAM. How to clear RAM after recursion?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, recursion, python-requests, psycopg2

I need to download 400k records through API and store it locally into DB. Every request returns 500 records + cursor for the next page. I use recursion and I see that `python3` process every recursion consumes more RAM (around 50 MB per recursion, so I need to have 40 GB RAM to download everything). What is the way to clear RAM after each recursion?

```
import os
import psycopg2
import requests

from psycopg2.extras import execute_values


class SomeClass:
    def __init__:
        with psycopg2.connect(
            host='localhost',
            dbname=os.getenv("POSTGRES_DBNAME"),
            user=os.getenv("POSTGRES_USER"),
            password=os.getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
        ) as self.conn:
            self.products_download_n_save()

    def products_download_n_save(self, cursor=''):
        basic_url = 'SOME_URL'

        if not cursor:
            url = basic_url
        else:
            url = f'{basic_url}?cursor={cursor}'

        r = requests.get(url)
        response = r.json()
        products = response['products']

        # Need to loop every product, because different product have different amount of fields 
        for product_d in products:
            values = [[value for value in product_d.values()]]

            columns = product_d.keys()
            do_update_query = ','.join([f'{column} = excluded.{column}' for column in columns])

            query = f"INSERT INTO {self.PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME} ({','.join(columns)}) VALUES %s " \
                    f"on conflict(productCode) " \
                    f"DO UPDATE SET {do_update_query};"

            with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
                execute_values(cursor, query, values)

        self.conn.commit()

        response_cursor = response.get('nextCursor', '')

        if response_cursor:
            self.products_download_n_save(response_cursor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution - move the code from recursion to `while response_cursor` loop.